# Payload contains two or more files

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm running into a problem with my references between projects in my UWP app. I keep getting the following error when I compile.

```
 ...\VisualStudio\v14.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets(1692,5): error APPX1101: Payload contains two or more files with the same destination path 'Microsoft.Win32.Primitives.dll'. Source files: 
 ...\VisualStudio\v14.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets(1692,5): error APPX1101: [NUGET_PATH]\.nuget\packages\Microsoft.Win32.Primitives\4.0.0\lib\dotnet\Microsoft.Win32.Primitives.dll
 ...\VisualStudio\v14.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets(1692,5): error APPX1101: [NUGET_PATH]\.nuget\packages\runtime.win.Microsoft.Win32.Primitives\4.0.1\runtimes\win\lib\netstandard1.3\Microsoft.Win32.Primitives.dll
 .
 .
 .
```

I've attached a sample app that reproduces the problem. I'm using nuget packages   (**FlickrNet, Instasharp, UWP Toolkit**) within my solution. Obviously if I remove all reference between projects, the solution compiles fine.

https://1drv.ms/u/s!AkM_7yXYPcncm5JGyUaqR5w_jYhnLA

I can't seem to understand the reason for "Duplicates" and how to fix it.

Comment: Seems to be an issue in [Instasharp](https://github.com/InstaSharp/InstaSharp), see [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/InstaSharp/InstaSharp/issues/128).

Comment: Thanks Jay for the quick reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the solution! I simply had to update the Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform package in the solution to fix the issue.